# how ms-access and sql server interact each other?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an ms-access database and I need when ever I add a record to my table automatically add a similar record to sql database how it is possible ?

**Edit**: How I can create an SSIS package(s) and  set SQL Server Agent run to periodically load the data?

Comment: Can you link the SQL database? Is there a reason why you do not wish to use the SQL database for the back-end, rather than Jet/ACE (Access)? Alternatively, would running an update query against the SQL server be an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2000 you can use replication. But this feature is deprecated from SQL Server 2005 onwards. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143470.aspx.

Assuming that you are on a later version, there are a couple of options I can see:

1) Migrate from Access to SQL Server Express and use replication.

2) Create an SSIS package(s) to import the data. The package(s) can be scheduled in SQL Server Agent run to periodically load the data.